# Lambda as iterator in Python returns function object on first iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, lambda

I have this code snippet which I can't understand:

```
>>> l = lambda: -4, 'c', 0
>>> i = iter(l)
>>> i
<tuple_iterator object at 0x00700CD0>
>>> next(i)
<function <lambda> at 0x0070A4F8>
>>> next(i)
'c'
>>> next(i)
0
>>> next(i)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

Why is it returning lambda object on first iteration, instead of -4?

Comment: You should use `next(i)()`. Because `next(i)`  only returns the lambda object.

Comment: Ok. But any explanation to what I'm facing here .. ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood what `l` is.

`l` is a tuple of 3 elements:

- a lambda that returns -4
- the string `c`
- the integer 0

When you create an iterator iterating through the tuple, of course the first call to `next` is going to give you a lambda!

Maybe you meant to call the lambda:

```
next(i)()
```

Or maybe you meant to declare `l` like this:

```
l = lambda: (-4, 'c', 0) # you might think you don't need the parentheses, but you do
```

A lambda that returns a tuple.

And then do `iter(l())`.

Comment: Great, appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

When you do this :

```
>>> l = lambda: -4, 'c', 0
```

`l` is actually a tuple containing first item as a lambda function, second item a string and third item an integer.

It is equivalent to the following :

```
>>> l = (lambda: -4, 'c', 0)
```

If you want to get access to the lambda function which returns `-4`, you should try this :

```
>>> i = iter(l)
>>> next(i)()
-4
```

But note that `next(i)()` works only with `callable`(lambda, functions etc) objects. If you use `next(i)()` with a string object python will raise `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. So always check if the item is `callable`. ie,

```
i = iter(l)
item = next(i)
if callable(item):
    print(item())
else:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Eagle eye, Thx.